# How to click on link text resides inside font tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the link based on the link name. Could someone help me to get XPATH to identify element using link name(Doors).

Below is the code I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Doors')]")).click();
```

HTML of that page. I want to click if the link text is Doors:

```
<div align="center">
    <a href="javascript:replace('2');">
        <img border="0" align="middle" src="http://test.com/m2o2/images/product_doors.png">
    </a>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <a href="javascript:replace('2');">
            <font color="Black"> Doors </font>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `By.linkText`:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Doors")).click();
```

Or, if that doesn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Doors")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Doors')]")).click();
```

with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),' Doors ')]")).click();
```